# Is there a tutorial how to compile my own monero cli wallet software from source?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, source, compile, cli

Is there an easy to follow guide on how to compile my own monero cli wallet from source code? I want to modify some very minor settings that has to do with initial wallet creation settings specifically the **ask-password** variable. Currently the **ask-password** variable on wallet creation is set to 1 as default. I want it to be 0 when creating a wallet as it doesn't seem like this can be set globally from a .conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling from source instructions are in the project [README](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/README.md#compiling-monero-from-source).

Though changing the Monero source code just to deviate from a sensible default value, which can be easily changed as soon as the wallet has been created in any case, seems a pointless exercise to me.

Comment: the end result what I really want to do is be able to do a "refresh" of multiple monero private keys at once. if i can't edit the source code to do this that would be great, but currently I need to do all these weird work around's just to make this a reality by creating a wallet and then doing a periodic refresh for each address with its own instance.

Comment: Point is, as soon as you've created them, you just run set ask-password 0 straight after, once. It's one extra step at creation.